K6 Open function throws cannot find the path specified error when relative path is used


import { SharedArray } from 'k6/data';

const data = new SharedArray('some name', function () {
  // All heavy work (opening and processing big files for example) should be done inside here.
  // This way it will happen only once and the result will be shared between all VUs, saving time and memory.
  const f = JSON.parse(open('..\\inputs\\sample.json'));
  return f; // f must be an array
});

export default function () {
  const element = data[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length)];
  console.log(element);
}



const data = new SharedArray('some name', function () {
// All heavy work (opening and processing big files for example) should be done inside here.
// This way it will happen only once and the result will be shared between all VUs, saving time and memory.
const f = JSON.parse(open('../sample.json'));
return f; // f must be an array
});
The above code sample as per the K6 documentation sample.
per the sample code in document the “Open” function should allow absolute or relative paths. but my observation is that the relative paths do not work. The Open function in the code above is used only in ‘init’ context. If i provide absolute path like c:\a\b\c’ then the Open function works
but when used relative paths its throwing error
ERRO[0000] GoError: CreateFile inputs\sample.json: The system cannot find the path specified.
at go.k6.io/k6/js.(*Bundle).setInitGlobals.func3 (native)
at file:///-:28:28(5)
at file:///-:27:12(46) hint=“script exception”

Where is your test script stored? How do you execute it? Does '../inputs/sample.json' (forward slashes) work?

@knittl the files are stored locally , I am using Windows OS, and K6 OSS 0.5.0
I execute the scripts using SImple K6 run ..l
Its a pure vanilla setup and does not involve any CI or Cloud infrastructure. I simply  used the sample given the documents and it just does not work.

For the file path I tried forward slash and backward slash both (offcourse adding escaping backslash)  no matter what only absolute path works with  same code. as provided above.

But what is the location of your test script? What is your working directory? Does ls -l ../inputs/sample.json work and show the file? Are you using the correct relative path?

Hmm i think i got what  you're saying . If i execute the script from root of my Project i get this error. But if I change directory to where the script is then i do not get the error.  Thank you for answering. I will adjust my Imports accordingly.  :)
Info

Paths in open calls are relative to the working directory, not the script location. You have to cd into the correct directory first or update your open calls to match your intended working directory.
